# How to redeploy a docker image using jenkin pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I created a pipeline for spring boot microservice project. I am automating the deployment process using jenkin pipeline. 
The steps which I used in pipeline as follows:
Jenkin script first checkout code from bitbucket.
Build a project using maven. 
Create a docker image.
Push docker image to dockerhub.
Then run this docker image by downloading docker image from docker hub.

It works perfectly one time. It would works second time as I need to stop docker conatiner and then remove image from there.

.

I used docker run -rm  According to documentation -rm is used to removed image form docker. But this not working any one help me out in this case

docker run --rm -p 8761:8761 -d --name ccpserviceregistry mydockerRepo/ccpserviceregistry:1.0

Want to redeploye the image with latest one .

Comment: what do you mean by 'this not working'? You get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Checkout code from bitbucket
- Build project using maven
- Create docker image
- Push docker image to dockerhub
- Remove if any docker container already running `docker rm -f container-name`
- Remove docker image if you want to if any (`docker rmi -f image-name`)
- Run docker image (use `--name` option in docker run so that it will be easier while removing the container, no need to provide `--rm` option)

Hope this helps.

Comment: These both required    docker rm -f container-name &&  docker rmi -f image-name

Comment: These commands will remove any already running container and images.